# How to upload attachment in message extension

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am looking for solution where I could upload an attachment in message extension.

So far, I am able to get the button in the hero card, but how can:

- I use this button to upload a file?, or
- Through this button I could open a new Adaptive Card or any card, where I use upload logic?

Attaching image below[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know You can't upload attachment using the [actions/buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-actions) functionality of TeamsCards.
However you can use [Teams TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) which allows you to create modal popup window in your Teams application.

Inside the popup window you can run your own custom HTML/JavaScript code where you can use the [<input type="file">](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) tag to upload your attachment.

To open a popup window you have to include "msteams":{"type":"task/fetch"} into "data" object of the action object of the card.
I used [AdaptiveCardDesigner](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to create an example for you.
But i think it's not necessary to use Adaptive Cards to achieve this, this should work with HeroCards too.

So here's an example:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Request Task"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3",
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Open Task Window",
            "data": {
                "msteams": {
                    "type": "task/fetch"
                },
                "messageId": "12345"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Next step is to handle this request on the backend and reply with an URL for the TaskModule window.

[Here's an example project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs) from Microsoft.

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta:

Oleksa has provide accurate solution for this question.